# How can I set fixed text for twitter posts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I would like the twitter posts from my app to be fixed so that users cannot edit them before posting. How can I achieve this? Below is the basic code I am using to post normal editable text.

```
-(void)tweetResults   {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from my own app! :)"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    CCLOG(@"it's working okay");
        }
}
```

Comment: Not allowing users to change the text doesn't seem like a good idea, and would probably result in less people tweeting from your app

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be either subclassing SLComposeViewController, or creating your own custom class using lower level API access to the users Twitter account.